# How to post JSON Array in retrofit using android?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am working on retrofit but i have no idea how to post JSONArray in retrofit, i am posting the sample JSON please kindly go through it.

```
{
    "tab": [{
            "menu_item_id": "",
            "cost": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "name": ""
    }]
}
```

I am able to create JSONObject model but i am facing some issue in JSONArray model please kindly go through my sample JSON and suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you declare the post method in your api interface? 
It should be something like this:

```
@POST("your/tabs/api/service/url") 
void postItemsMethod(@Field("tabs[]") ArrayList<YourItemClass> tabs , Callback<CallBackClass> callback);
```

Comment: You are welcome!, don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it answers your question. Have a nice day.

Comment: hey how to get raw JSON in response body in retrofit